# String после завершения метода

Tags: c++

Имеется метод в классе Saves:

```
string Saves::getTitle()
{
    XMLDocument save;
    save.LoadFile("./saves/slot.xml");

    XMLElement* nameElement = save.FirstChildElement("Save")->FirstChildElement("Slot")->FirstChildElement("Name");
    string name = nameElement->GetText();

    return name;
}
```

В одном из файлов я создаю экземпляр класса, и вызываю этот метод:

```
string textSaveTitle;
textSaveTitle == save.getTitle();
cout << textSaveTitle;
```

В XML файле в нужном месте написано "123". При использовании cout внутри метода эта строка выводится, однако при использовании вне метода ничего не выводится. В чём я совершил ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите лишний символ `=` в

```
textSaveTitle == save.getTitle();
```

Вы не присваиваете, а сравниваете...